# React how to handle CRUD with useReducer and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having problem to manage the add action

using useReducer and useEffect if for the load

action I've worked it out with

```
const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialTodoState);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTodos = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const todos = await response.json();
      dispatch({ type: Action.LOAD, payload: todos });
    };
    fetchTodos();
  }, []);
```

but what's the way to useEffect passing the todo value?
Is this the right way ?

```
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        if(todo){
          // fetch data 
        }
      }, [todo]);
 const submitHandler = (todo: string) => {
        setTodo(todo);
      };
```

Comment: Just an aside, do you need `await` in front of `response.json()` - isn't `.json()` synchronous?

Comment: Also response.json() is a promise